# Table in the migrated website is not displaying properly : Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I just migrated a website from shared server to Windows server 2008. The table displaying contents in a website is not showing properly in the Windows server 2008(asp.net 4, IIS 6), but good in the shared server.

From the Windows Server 2008::

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LvcPHGB.png]

From shared server::

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vMCNHvD.png]

I hope somebody can give me a clue. This may not be an issue with code as it is working properly in the shared server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately it is now resolved. It was an issue with css id, but not sure how this mismatch happened.

This was found by checking from the browser, "Inspect Element"

I am not well aware about codes and css, but "Inspect Element" helped me out

Thank you.